# Where do the characters obtain their weapons?

Tags: angel-n-devil

On the show *Angel 'N' Devil*, various characters, mostly Energy Users, have magic weapons.

We know that Charlie Wang's weapon, Excalibur, is not simply a manifestation of his powers, but used to belong to another person. However, virtually all the Bad Girls have weapons, and in fact Yin Hsiao-Feng had her magic fan before even joining, which leans toward these weapons being intrinsic to their powers.

Further, not every energy user has a weapon (like A-Tien Wang) and at least the one Daycrawler at the beginning had a weapon.

Where do most of the characters acquire their weapons? Are they all passed down through the ages like Excalibur? Are some of them manifestations of an Energy User's own powers?

Comment: Someone aiming for a Tumbleweed badge, I see... :-)

Comment: @Valorum - I already have one.